# How do I directly access the shares of a machine?

Tags: nautilus, networking

I don't want to navigate via the Networks --> workgroup/domain folder.  I want to skip that step and directly access the share of a specific machine.

For example, in Windows you would type in Windows Explorer:

```
\\MachineName
```

and it would open up the shares of that machine.  How can I do this in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 6):

I'm assuming you are talking about shares on a Windows machine. I usually just open a nautilus window and type

```
smb://machinename
```

then press enter.

You might need to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> in Nautilus to get the location bar to put than it.

That will show you the shares on that computer, including the administratively hidden ones like admin$ which a Windows client won't show you.

Answer (score 2):

You can bring up the Run Command interface (or `gnome-do`) trough the shortcut **Alt + F2** and insert machine's hostname as you would in Windows. Like:

[image]

Then, Enter or simply click **Run**

Answer (score 2):

Under Places > Connect to Server you can specify the details under Windows Shares.

It is self explanatory once you have the dialog box open.

[Details can be found here](http://library.gnome.org/users/user-guide/2.29/nautilus-server-connect.html.en).

If you bookmark that place in nautilus so it creates a bookmark in your left hand side bar, clicking on that bookmark in future will reconnect the share for you.